# how to get a grid effect presented on the following image?

Tags: css, html

I want to get the grid effect similar to one on the picture. Any ideas?

[sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eHOR0.png)

Comment: It is expected that you at least attempt to code this for yourself. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. I would suggest that you do some additional research, either via Google or by searching SO, make an attempt and. if you still have trouble, come back with your code and explain what you have tried and why it did not work.

Comment: You're looking for the CSS `background-image` property.

Comment: @RishitaParmar : How do you know I haven't tried? I did try to do this with gradient option. I don't know which values should I set. Maybe, I am wrong and it can't be done with gradient. Thank you everyone for answers. Is setting the background image the only option in this case?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `background-image` property to apply image as background:

```css
div {
  background-image: url('http://d1v8u1ev1s9e4n.cloudfront.net/54e5236f5ccacf314d464817');
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: repeat;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```